# Magento overriding template file doesnt work

Tags: magento

In ShopShark(this module for blog) i have this code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">

//a lot of code//

<blog_post_view>
    <remove name="left"/>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="blog/post" name="post" template="blog/post.phtml">
            <block type="blog/product_toolbar" name="blog_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>                   
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</blog_post_view>

// a lot of code //

</layout>
```

Next i try to change post page. I found the solution here http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-overriding-template-file-from-custom-module/ , but its doesnt work! My code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">

//a lot of code//

<blog_post_view>
    <action method="setTitle">
            <title>My Blog</title>
        </action>
    <reference name="post">
        <action method="setTemplate">               
            <template>test/post.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>

</blog_post_view>

// a lot of code //

</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are exactly trying to do is not clear.I think you messed up with the structural block here. I am not exactly sure but needed to see the xml file where you have created the block "post".If you have not created the block "post",then you cannot use the code

> `<reference name="post">`

From your code it seems that you are trying to change the template to post.phtml.

If that is the case than just change

> `<reference name="post">`

to `<reference name="content">`

other part seem fine.

Hope this will help!